# End of script output before headers: convertidor.cgi

Tags: html, perl

Tengo este mismo problema y ya verifiqué la sintáxis del script de Perl y veo que todo está correcto, no entiendo el motivo por el cual no funciona. Aquí está la maquetación del formulario:

```
<form id="formu" action="convertidor.cgi" method="POST" class="form register">
    <h2 class="form_titulo"> Convertidor de temperaturas </h2>
    <div class="contenedor-inputs">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="grados"  id="nombre" placeholder="Ingresa el número de grados  " maxlength="10" class="input-100" required  />
        <center>
            <input type="radio" name="conver" id="CF" value="CF" checked>
            <label for="CF">Celsius a farenheit</label>
            <input type="radio" name="conver" id="CK" value="CK">
            <label for="CK">Celsius a Kelvin</label>
            <input type="radio" name="conver" id="FC" value="FC">
            <label for="FC">Farenheit a celsius</label>
            <input type="radio" name="conver" id="FK" value="FK">
            <label for="FK">Farenheit a kelvin</label>
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="conver" id="KF" value="KF" >
            <label for="KF">Kelvin a celsius</label>
            <input type="radio" name="conver" id="KC" value="KC">
            <label for="KC">kelvin a celsius</label>
        </center>
        <center>
            <input class="form-btn" type="submit" id="btnenviar" value="Ingresar" />
        </center>
    </div>
```

y aquí el del script de Perl utilizando el módulo CGI:

```
#!"C:\xampp\perl\bin\perl.exe"

use strict;
use CGI;

my $cgi = new CGI;

my $n1 = $cgi->param('grados');
my $op = $cgi->param('conver');

if ($n1 !~ /[0-9]+$/) {
    print $cgi->header("text/html");
    print "Error ha ingresado datos incorrectos";
    return;
}

my $total;

if ($op eq "CF") {
    $total = (9*$n1)/5+32;
}
elsif ($op eq "CK") {
    $total = $n1+273.15;
}
elsif ($op eq "FC") {
    $total = 5*($n1-32)/9;
}
elsif ($op eq "FK") {
    $total = (5*($n1-32)/9)+273.15;
}
elsif ($op eq "KC") {
    $total = 9($n-273.15)/5+32
}
elsif ($op eq "KF") {
    $total = $n1-273.15
}

print $cgi->header("text/html");
print $total;
```

Answer (score 0):

La línea que tiene la fórmula **9($n-273.15)/5+32** está mal escrita (falta un operador después del '9'.

Usa la opción '-c' como te hemos comentado en otro hilo, para que Perl te avise de estos errores.

También, no dejes de ver el archivo error.log del servidor web, porque allí saldrán todos estos errores.